Is there a (PDF) manual for geometry nodes?
I am looking for a manual of sorts. The Blender one only gives the name of the nodes, but not much info as to their functions or examples of their use.
Tutorials are great, but very few explain the use of each node and how it functions in the tree.
I hope this makes sense and someone can point me in the correct direction. I would love to be able to get as comfortable with the nodes functions as Erindale. That's what I'm looking for: the information that he has in his head about each node; it's like he has a sheet with all the information.

There is one by Thijs Manders (YT channel "MTR Animation") on Gumroad, it is around 200 pages, but it also costs a bit. I really like his YT tutorials, but for me personally I don't think a PDF on the nodes would be very useful. First of all Geometry Nodes is evolving so rapidly, always new nodes in each release, and the other things is - understanding the functionality is one thing, but knowing what interesting things you can do with it something else. I prefer tutorials where people create amazing stuff with nodes which you might not even think of just by knowing what their function is.

Apart from that, I think Erindale teaches himself a lot by just using the nodes and testing what he can do with them. Learning by doing so that you understand and know by heart what a node is for is the key here - I doubt he gets everthing "in his head" by reading a manual about it. A general understanding of maths also helps by creating stuff with nodes, at least the more awesome things that some people show in their tutorials. And finally, this question is more or less off-topic here, since this site aims to answer specific problems while working with Blender, not advice on resources.
